# ASP.Net MVC view unable to see HtmlHelper extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

We're going through an ASP.Net MVC book and are having trouble with using an extenstion method within our view.  The Extension method looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcBookApplication
{
  public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
  {
    public static string JQueryGenerator(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formName, object model);
  }
}
```

We use the extension method in our view like this:

```
    <%=Html.JQueryGenerator("createmessage", ViewData.Model)%>
```

The problem is, that line of code says JQueryGenerator isn't a recognized method of HtmlHelper.  I believe we've got the correct references set in the web project, but are there other things we can check?  There's no using statement for views, is there?

Comment: As Gregoire said, you can either add the MvcBookApplication namespace in the web.config by adding
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcBookApplication" />
    </namespaces>
</pages> 
inside the system.web section in your web.config, or you can either put a <%@ Import Namespace="MvcBookApplication" %> at the beginning of the view that contains the call to the helper method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added a reference to `MvcBookApplication` namespace in your web.config ?

Comment: Sounds like a definite possibility.  We'll check it out.

Comment: That was it, the namespace wasn't referenced.